# Perl and LVN_COLUMNCLICK; works fine under WinXP x86, but not under Win7 x64. Why?

Tags: perl, winapi

I have this perl subroutine that works fine under WinXP x86, sorting a column for a 32 bit application among other things, but under Win7 x64  this subroutine doesn't work at all. The others work fine(tabs switching, pressing buttons, etc). Any idea why?

```
sub function      
{
my @searchresultswindow_handle = FindWindowLike( @_[ 0 ], undef, undef, $searchresultswindow_id );
 if( !@searchresultswindow_handle  )
  {
   die "Cannot find window handle for searchresultswindow control\n";
  }
 else
  {
   printf( "searchresultswindow handle is %x\n", $searchresultswindow_handle[ 0 ] );

            $keysList=@searchresultswindow_handle[0] ;

        my $action = pack( "l l",
        0, #ptaction.x
        0 #ptaction.y
        );

        my $action_ptr = unpack( 'L!', pack( 'P',$action));

        my $str_buf = pack( "L L L l l L L L L l",
        $keysList, #nmh.hdr.hwndFrom hwnd
        0, #nmh.hdr.idFrom

        4294967188, #LVN_COLUMNCLICK ,#nmh.hdr.code Code
        -1, #item
  13, #sub item
        0, #uNewState
        0, #uOldState
        0, #uChanged
        $action_ptr, #action
        0 #lparam
        );

          $lvitem = AllocateVirtualBuffer( $keysList, 5000 );
        WriteToVirtualBuffer( $lvitem, $str_buf ); 


  my $value =PostMessage( $keysList, 0x004E, 0, $lvitem->{ 'ptr' });
FreeVirtualBuffer( $lvitem );
}
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work at all"? What happens, and what errors do you get?

Comment: Yeah, and throw us a bone and tell us what modules `FindWindowLike` and `AllocateVirtualBuffer` come from.

Comment: 1) I forgot to say that $keysList and $lvitem are declared global(unnecesary, but I forgot to correct the issue before posting). 2) Underwin7 x64, all other parts of the script work fine, except for this one. This part is supposted to click on a header subitem(to sort the window's items by size, for example) for a specific window.

Comment: 3)AllocateVirtualBuffer  http://www.piotrkaluski.com/files/winguitest/docs/ch09.html#AllocateVirtualBuffer                                                       FindWindowLike http://www.piotrkaluski.com/files/winguitest/docs/ch09s05.html       both are Win32::GuiTest subroutines.

Comment: LE: 2*) Under Win7 x64 the script runs this subroutine, no errors or anything, but the items aren't sorted, because, probably, the parent window doesn't receive the notification message, or doesn't execute it. There's something different under Win7 x64, compared to WinXP x86. And I don't know what is that something.

Comment: You can try asking in this mailing list: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/perlguitest/

Answer (score 1):

The structures are packed differently on 32 and 64 bit systems.

on 32-bit:

```
0:000> dt tagNMHDR
notepad!tagNMHDR
   +0x000 hwndFrom         : Ptr32 HWND__
   +0x004 idFrom           : Uint4B
   +0x008 code             : Uint4B
```

on 64-bit:

```
0:000> dt tagNMHDR
kernel32!tagNMHDR
   +0x000 hwndFrom         : Ptr64 HWND__
   +0x008 idFrom           : Uint8B
   +0x010 code             : Uint4B
```

Comment: It works fine on WinXP x64. I think it's a problem related to UIPI. I haven't solved it yet, though.

Comment: Is perl.exe 64-bit or 32-bit on these systems?   If you suspect UIPI - did you try starting your scrip from an elevated cmd.exe ("run as administrator")

Comment: Yes, I ran the script as admin. It did not work. I've installed both Perl versions 64/32bit. I've even wrote a C++ program that has the same behaviour, it works fine on WinXP x86/x64, but not on Win7 x86/x64.